# Fourth moment of a non negative random variable

Tags: probability-theory

If $X$ is a nonnegative real random variable,with finite expectations and mean,is it possible to find an expression for $E(X^4)$ in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2?$ I will be highly obliged for any help \hints

Comment: I suspect that, in general, such a expression exists. What is the context of your question?

Comment: THERE ARE MANY INSTANCES WHERE THE EVEN MOMENTS ONLY ARE KNOWN.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Can you give an example?

Comment: if you consider the norm  of a polynomial on a unit circcle,all the even monements of $|p(z)|$ can be computed ,where z ranges uniformly on the circle.However,we cannot compute the odd moments.

Comment: No, no such expression exists.  Finite variance doesn't even guarantee that $E[X^4] < \infty$.  Even if we assume $E[X^4] < \infty$, it can still be arbitrary.  For example, let $Y$ be a nonnegative random variable with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, and $E[Y^4] = \infty$.  We can define $X = Y1_{Y \le c}$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ to get a random variable with mean at most $\mu$, variance at most $\sigma^2$, and (almost) any positive value for $E[X^4]$.